# URL redirects within drupal 7 site breaking image display in blocks

Tags: blocks, media, uri

I am developing a drupal 7 site where 4 pages have url redirects from a parent page within the site. I have a block in the footer that is shown on all pages but the 4 pages mentioned above do not display the image within that block. I'm thinking that it must have something to do with the redirects as it is only these 4 pages that don't display the image. All other pages with that block show the image up just fine.

Comment: Well, most likely this image that is inside the block has a non-relative path? can you paste the block contents?

Comment: Here are the contents <div class="img-holder-getintouch"><img src="sites/default/files/footer-get-in-touch.png" alt="" width="250" height="291" /></div> etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation a recommendation is to use relative path and not activate if this is your only reason the php as input type.
Your code will be

```
div class="img-holder-getintouch"><img src="/sites/default/files/footer-get-in-touch.png" alt="" width="250" height="291" /></div>
```

You will see that i added just a slash as of this tells the site to request the file from http://www.example.com/sites....
this way you can do a migration and the images will still work.

Comment: Are u sure that the site is/will always be hosted on apache/server document root?? This will not be valis if thats the case..

Comment: For more than enough situation this will be accepted solution. To activate php is also a solution but will involve some changes that is not necessary from the start. At the end user will decide what fit his need.

Comment: @Drupalizeme - Thanks for the extra slash advice - it worked a treat!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this image will play nice only if you are in your homepage or something and then the relative path is as: `http://site.com/sites/default/files/footer-get-in-touch.png`

Off course this won't play for other paths as this is invalid

`http://site.com/<PATH>/sites/default/files/footer-get-in-touch.png`

Quick Solution:

Enable php filter module, to be able to write php inside the blocks contents and provide correct image path for all cases

```
<?php 
    global $base_path;
?>
<div class="img-holder-getintouch">
    <img src="<?php echo $base_path; ?>sites/default/files/footer-get-in-touch.png" alt="" width="250" height="291" />
</div>
```